# R - Calling a function chosen at random

Tags: r

If I have created 100 different functions, say:

```
abc()
def()
...
ghi()
jkl()
```

Inside of a new function, what's the best way to call one of these chosen at random?

Comment: The best way is to not have created them as separate objects, but instead put all the functions in a list, and then select a function from the list at random.

Comment: So like this? `all <- list(abc, def, ... , ghi, jkl)` and then to call a random function `all[[sample(1:length(all),1]]()`

Comment: @AndrewK - I think that's definitely the path to go down. You can answer your own question if you like to close it off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a list `all <- list(abc, def, ... , ghi, jkl)` and then call a random function from the list `all[[sample(1:length(all),1]]()`